# Scope in Angurlarjs

Tags: angularjs-scope

```
var myApp = angular.module("appModule", ["integralui"]);
myApp.controller("appCtrl", function($scope,$http){
     $http.get('http://localhost:8080/er')
     .then(function(response) {
         window.alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
         $scope.datacheck = response.data;
        $scope.treeName = "treesample";
        $scope.showLines = true;
        $scope.toggleLines = function(elem){
            $scope.showLines = !$scope.showLines;
        }
        $scope.datacheck =[
                        { 
                            id: 1,
                            text: "Item1",
                            items: [
                                { id: 11, pid: 12, text: "Item12" },

                            ]
                        },
                        { id: 7, text: "Item7" }
                    ];

     });         
     $scope.data =[
                    { 
                        id: 1,
                        text: "Item1",
                        items: [
                            { id: 11, pid: 1, text: "Item12" },

                        ]
                    },
                    { id: 7, text: "Item7" }
                ];

});
```

When i am trying to get data from the database and put that it into scope.datacheck it is not working with the treeview plugin which i have using. scope.data is working fine. Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: you are putting your `response.data` in `userdata` and not in `datacheck`. Please check your question once.

Comment: Sorry for that. now corrected.
Scope.datacheck is not working with treeview plugin but scope.data is working. i have tried in many ways but the result is same.

Comment: what do you mean with : `$scope.datacheck` is not working. What are you expecting from database? your `$scope.datacheck` is being rewritten each time after you bring something from the database.